# How to get path relative to the working directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, relative-path

I have a script that recursively loops through all `.txt` files in the working directory and subdirectories and does something with that files. Now I would like to exclude all files in certain subdirectories that are listed in a `exclude.txt` file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
    CALL:processFile %%f %%~df%%~pf
)
GOTO:EOF

:processFile
    SET file_=%~1
    SET path_=%~2                 <- %%~df%%~pf is the full path :(
    find "!path_!" exclude.txt
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 (
        REM do something here
    )
    GOTO:EOF
```

However, `%%/~df%%~pf` expands to the absolute path. **How can I get the path relative to the workingdirectory?** I want to list only the subdirectories in `exclude.txt` and not the full paths.

PS: I could of course read the relative paths from `exclude.txt`, append `%cd%` and write them to some `exclude.temp` and then search in this temporary file, but I hope there is a nicer way.

Comment: You can't use a GOTO inside a FOR command without breaking it.

Comment: Reverse your thought process.  Use FINDSTR and use it's /G option.  Use the exclude text as your search strings.  `echo %%F |findstr /G:exclude.txt`. Regardless of that code change you still can't use GOTO inside your FOR command code block.

Comment: @Squashman ups didnt notice, because I am testing the script with a single file only. I changed it, hope it is ok now

Comment: Why call out to a label to do that.  That just slows down your processing if you have a lot of files to process.  Just use the IF command inside your FOR code block.

Comment: @Squashman ups sure, I was looking how to use a label inside for and then I didnt realize that I dont need it at all. Edited again.

Comment: I gave you the code in my comment.  What don't you understand?

Comment: in your example code, _(as edited)_, `%%f` is the absolute path including filename which is set as `%file_%` from `%~1`. `%%~df%%~pf` is better written as `%%~dpf` and is the folder including a trailing backslash where the file `%%~nxf` is located. This in your code will be set to `%path_%` from `%~2`.

Comment: Eliminate current directory in this way: `SET "path_=!path_:*%cd%=!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r %%F in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%F|findstr /I /G:exclude.txt >nul 2>&1
    IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (
        REM do something here
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for your patience. I am really noob in batch. Can I use something else in place of `echo`? I would prefer not to display the result of findstr

Comment: @tobi303, code has been updated to redirect standard output and standard error to nul.

Comment: You could avoid delayed expansion if you used `if not ErrorLevel 1` or even the `&&` operator...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach, relying on the fact that `xcopy` is capable of returning relative paths. Since we do not want to copy anything, the `/L` switch needs to be used (list but do not copy).

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    xcopy /L /I /S ".\*.txt" "%TEMP%" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    echo(Relative path to file: "%%~F"

    rem // This block is only needed in case the leading `.\` disturbs:
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(Relative path, no `.\`: "!FILE:*.\=!"
    endlocal
)
```