# How to test if path is listed in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, relative-path

I had almost the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746300/how-to-get-path-relative-to-the-working-directory) for a windows script, but now I need to do the same in linux.

I have a script that recursively finds all `.h` files and checks if there is a `.cpp` file in the same directory with the same name. So far this works, but now I would like to use a `Exclude.txt` file that contains folders that should be excluded. My problem is that `$file` is the full path, but in `Exclude.txt` I want to list only the paths relative to `$pwd`. How can I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find ${PWD} -name '*.h'); do 
    fileWithoutPath=$(basename $file)
    fileWithoutExtension=${fileWithoutPath%.*}
    prefix="$(dirname $file)/"
    suffix=".cpp"
    cppFile=$prefix$fileWithoutExtension$suffix

    if ??? path is not listed in ./Exclude.txt  ???   <--- what to put here?
        if [ -f "$cppFile" ]
        then
            echo "FILE EXISTS"
        else 
            echo "FILE DOES NOT EXIST"
        fi
    fi      
done
```

As an example:

```
script is in:         /u/workingDir/
Exclude has a line:   foo
```

then all files in `/u/workingDir/foo/` should be ignored.

Comment: @Gnqz yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a perl one-liner to convert the absolute path of `$prefix` to a relative path that's relative to `$PWD` (let's call it `$relPath`):

```
echo "$prefix" #=> /u/workingDir/foo/bar/
relPath=$(perl -e 'use File::Spec; print File::Spec->abs2rel(@ARGV) . "\n"' $prefix $PWD)
echo "$relPath" #=> foo/bar (<-- This is what you'd put into Exclude.txt)
```

Next, we'll use grep to check if `$relPath` is listed in `Exclude.txt`. If it is, we'll ignore that directory, and if it's not, then we'll check if `$cppFile` exists:

```
if ! grep -xqF "$relPath" ./Exclude.txt; then
   # Check for file...
   if [ -f "$cppFile" ]
      ...
   fi
else
   echo "IGNORE $relPath"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
relPathToFile=${file#$PWD}      # remove $PWD from beginning
while read -r excludePath; do
    if [[ $relPathToFile == $excludePath/* ]]; then
        if [[ -f $cppFile ]]; then
            ...
    fi
 done < './Exclude.txt'
```

Comment: could you explain what this is supposed to do? When I try this it seems like the condition always evaluates to true

Comment: maybe I wasnt clear enough in the question. There are no lines in Exclude.txt that exactly match the prefix. Instead in Exclude.txt I want to list the paths relative to $pwd. For example: script runs in $pwd, Exclude.txt contains somePath, then $pwd\somePath\ should be excluded

Comment: But doesn't `$prefix` already contain the path relative to `$PWD`?

Comment: Oh, of course, I didn't notice you were doing `find "$PWD"`.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

The idea: cut off the `$PWD` prefix, then you can `grep` for the result in the file.

This will cut the current directory prefix off `$filename`:

```
stripped_file=${filename##$PWD/}
```

An example:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo $PWD
/tmp
$ filename='/tmp/foo.txt'
$ echo ${filename##$PWD/}
foo.txt
```

Reuse this trick to see if a relative path includes the stripped file name:

```
if [ "$stripped_file_name" != "${stripped_file_name##$relative_path}" ]; then
   # hey, removing the relative path worked, so the file must be
   # on the relative path; go on.
fi
```

Else you might *prepend* `$PWD` to relative paths to make them absolute, and see if they are a prefix of the absolute file path.

Comment: thats almost what I need. `stripped_file` still contains the file name, but I want only the (relative) path, so that I can exclude full subdirectories, and dont have to list individual files in the Exclude.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could use `readlink -f $some_file_name` to get the full filename, then you could just check if the file is in the list.

Comment: but the full file name contains also the $pwd part and this part I do not want to list in Exclude.txt

Comment: Try this [exclude-directory-from-find-command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command). The shell script can be modified to exclude files read from the exclude.txt file.